# How can I export all google analytics datas in BigQuery

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I use Firebase for my iOS app. Aleready, I connected with Google Analytics and BigQuery.
My Google Analytics has datas over 2 months. I connected with BigQuery before over 24hors.

However, BigQuery has only 4 days datas. Why BigQuery has not all days?

Now, I use free plan for BigQuery. Free paln cause this problem?

I look forward to hearing from your answer!! (My english is so bad,,, sorry,,,)

---

Already, This question soloved in [this][1].

BigQuery cannot export all data from google analytics.
So, Google Analytics Reporting Api can use all data.
But, I only needed a little data, and I manually exported it as a csv file from Analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is only exported from Google/Firebase Analytics to BigQuery from the moment you enable the integration. Historical data is not exported, no matter what plan (free/paid) your project is on.